# Regex is skipping 2nd line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/Hero\s+(\d+):\s+Name:\s+(\w+)\s+Lane:\s+(\w+)/g
```

I am testing it on the following text:

> Team A Draft: Hero 1: Name: Pugna Lane: Mid
>
> Hero 2: Name: Faceless Void Lane: Safelane
>
> Hero 3: Name: Earthshaker Lane: Offlane
>
> Hero 4: Name: Lion Lane: Support
>
> Hero 5: Name: Lina Lane: Support

Using the following function in javascript:

```
    function getHeroMap(text) {
    const heroRegex = /Hero\s+(\d+):\s+Name:\s+(\w+)\s+Lane:\s+(\w+)/g;
    let match;
    const heroes = [];

    while ((match = heroRegex.exec(text)) !== null) {
        const [, position, hero, lane] = match;
        heroes.push({
            position: parseInt(position),
            hero: hero,
            lane: lane.trim()
        });
    }

    return heroes;
}
```

However it seems to skip the 2nd hero as the result is:

```
 [
    {
        "position": 1,
        "hero": "Pugna",
        "lane": "Mid"
    },
    {
        "position": 2,
        "hero": "Earthshaker",
        "lane": "Offlane"
    },
    {
        "position": 3,
        "hero": "Rubick",
        "lane": "Support"
    },
    {
        "position": 4,
        "hero": "Juggernaut",
        "lane": "Safe"
    }
]
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `\w` matches any word character, not spaces. Your second hero name contains a space.

Comment: You may use: `/\bHero\s+(\d+):\s+Name:\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\s+Lane:\s+(\w+)/g`

Comment: Not perfect but this is a little looser constructed regex. `Hero\s+(\d+):\s+Name\s*:\s+(\w+(?:\s*\w)*)\s+Lane\s*:\s+(\w+(?:[^\S\r\n]*\w)*)`  https://regex101.com/r/WyUhs7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simpliest modification that should work - just including whitespace characters in the group:

```
/Hero\s+(\d+):\s+Name:\s+([\w\s]+)\s+Lane:\s+(\w+)/g
```

But that's assuming that hero names don't contain any special characters, such as `'` or `-`. This regex will cover all cases except when there's `:` in a name - it matches anything except that character:

```
/Hero\s+(\d+):\s+Name:\s+([^:]+)\s+Lane:\s+(\w+)/g
```

And this should cover anything including `:` - it matches anything in a non-greedy way:

```
/Hero\s+(\d+):\s+Name:\s+(.*?)\s+Lane:\s+(\w+)/g
```